# Anonymous access to controller action fails

Tags: controller

I have this controller, and I've set $allowAnonymous to true, but I'm still getting redirect to CP login:

```
class SitemapController extends BaseController
{
    protected $allowAnonymous = true;

    public function actionXml()
    {
        ...
        $this->renderTemplate('sitemap/list.xml', array(
            'entries' => $entries,
            'sections' => $enabledSections
        ));        
    }

}
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: What does your route look like?

Comment: No routes setup for this plugin. Trying to access it through the action url, like so: /index.php/admin/actions/sitemap/xml

Comment: Beats me. Your code looks legit. What happens if you remove everything inside ```actionXml()``` and just ```die( 'something' )```?

Comment: Still redirects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your URL is wrong.

Try `/index.php/actions/sitemap/sitemap/xml`

Here is the section of the docs that explains URLs for plugin controllers: http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/controllers#how-controller-actions-fit-into-routing

Comment: The url should be fine. I'm able to access it when logged in. This is also the url returned by actionUrl. The plugin in questions is named Sitemap, and has a single controller called SitemapController.

Comment: This answer should be correct. The "admin" segment is the reason you're redirected to the CP login; remove it and you should be fine.  Also, where are you calling ```actionUrl```? I just tested it in a frontend template, and it didn't prepend w/ "admin" on my end.

Comment: I believe the `siteMap` in the url needs to be camel-cased... This is a situation where the path isn't indicating a _directory_, it's indicating a _plugin class_ for the action routing to follow.

Comment: Nevermind, I see "Sitemap" in your controller name is all lowercase.

Comment: You were right - I was using a url returned from actionUrl within the admin, and forgot to remove the admin segment. Works superduper now.